# Hexbin with multiple groups in one plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I have a dataframe with millions of observation and thus need to display the results as a hexbin chart using `geom_hex()` or variant.

My plot is already faceted by `outcome~predicor`, so I would like the factor variable to be mapped to the `color/fill` aesthetic of the hex and the `alpha` to be mapped to the count/frequency of the observation.

In the code below I show what it looks like with a scatter plot but fail to make it work with hexbin. I realise that this mean that for each bin there will be `length(factor)` hexbins. I don't mind if they overlap.

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'tidyverse' was built under R version 4.2.3
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.2.3
#> Warning: package 'tibble' was built under R version 4.2.3
#> Warning: package 'tidyr' was built under R version 4.2.3
#> Warning: package 'readr' was built under R version 4.2.3
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 4.2.3
#> Warning: package 'forcats' was built under R version 4.2.3
#> Warning: package 'lubridate' was built under R version 4.2.3
set.seed(123) 
factor <- c(0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1)
predictor_name <- paste0("predictor_", LETTERS[1:5])
outcome_name <- paste0("outcome_", LETTERS[1:5])

df <- expand.grid(
  factor = factor,
  predictor_name = predictor_name,
  outcome_name = outcome_name
) %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    predictor_value = list(runif(100)),
    outcome_value = list(runif(100))
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  unnest(c(predictor_value, outcome_value))

#scatter plot coloured by factor
df %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = predictor_value , y = outcome_value, col = factor),
             alpha = 0.2) +
  facet_grid(outcome_name ~ predictor_name, scales = "free") +
  scale_color_viridis_b() +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

```r
# hex bin
df %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_hex(aes(x = predictor_value , 
                 y = outcome_value)) + # fill = factor, alpha = count
  facet_grid(outcome_name ~ predictor_name, scales = "free") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-09-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want each level of `factor` to have its own layer, and simply overlay the different layers on each other with different alpha according to the counts, then you can set the fill color to the `factor` variable, and the alpha to `after_stat(count)`. The effect is better with a smaller number of bins in this case, though the final plot is relatively difficult to interpret:

```r
df %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_hex(aes(x = predictor_value , y = outcome_value, fill = factor(factor),
               alpha = after_stat(count)), bins = 10) +
  facet_grid(outcome_name ~ predictor_name, scales = "free") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

If `factor` is to be treated as a numeric variable, and you want the average value of `factor` within each bin to determine the fill color, then you need to manually hexbin the data:

```r
cell_df <- do.call('rbind',
        split(df, interaction(df$outcome_name, df$predictor_name)) |>
  lapply(function(d) {
    hb <- hexbin::hexbin(d$predictor_value, d$outcome_value, 
                         xbins = 10, IDs = TRUE)
    cbind(aggregate(d$factor, by = list(hb@cID), FUN = mean),
          count = hb@count, X = hexbin::hcell2xy(hb)$x, 
          Y = hexbin::hcell2xy(hb)$y, outcome_name = d$outcome_name[1],
          predictor_name = d$predictor_name[1])
  }))

cell_df %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_hex(aes(x = X , y = Y, fill = x, alpha = count),
           stat = 'identity') +
  facet_grid(outcome_name ~ predictor_name, scales = "free") +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_fill_viridis_c() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, does that overlay the hex on that share the same bins or places them side by sideish?

Comment: @CyG it overlays them. Hexbins are space-filling, so you can't really have them side-by-sideish without your plot being a total mess. I have added a second option if you want the cells to contain the mean value of `factor`

Comment: Your edit is incredibly useful thank you